# Permissions for file share used by PC on same domain

Tags: windows, permissions, network-shares, windows-server-2012

I have created a script that runs on `\\Server` and writes to `\\BackupServer\BackupShare`. It works as expected when I run it myself.

I then setup a job in Windows Task Scheduler to run as `SYSTEM` and the same script fails with error `0x00000005` permission denied. How to fix this?

The share is located as `X:\BackupShare` on `BackupServer` with "inherited" permissions. I am sure I need to set share permissions as well but don't know how. Both machines are on same domain.

Comment: `SYSTEM` is a local account and therefore can't access other Windows PCs over network. You need to run the task using a domain account with proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the System account is a local account (see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/local-accounts#default-local-system-accounts).

> The SYSTEM account is used by the operating system and by services
>   that run under Windows. There are many services and processes in the
>   Windows operating system that need the capability to sign in
>   internally, such as during a Windows installation. The SYSTEM account
>   was designed for that purpose, and Windows manages the SYSTEM
>   account’s user rights. It is an internal account that does not show up
>   in User Manager, and it cannot be added to any groups.
>
> On the other hand, the SYSTEM account does appear on an NTFS file
>   system volume in File Manager in the Permissions portion of the
>   Security menu. By default, the SYSTEM account is granted Full Control
>   permissions to all files on an NTFS volume. Here the SYSTEM account
>   has the same functional rights and permissions as the Administrator
>   account.

The best way to solve this issue is create a seperate backup account with the least amount of rights needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could add permissions for `Server$` user in the active directory to that folder.